# Printf in a function changing the value of the output in main

Tags: c

I'm completely baffled by an unexpected behaviour of `printf()` function. I have two functions `main()` and `dfs()`. When I add a `printf()` statement in `dfs() function` I get the desired output in `main()` but when I don't add a `printf()` statement in `dfs()` function than I get the output as `0`.

Function - MAIN

```
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
        scanf("%lld",&P[i]);
    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
        scanf("%lld",&A[i]);
    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
        scanf("%lld",&H[i]);
    dfs(1,2,0);  minans += A[1];
    printf("**%lld\n",minans);
    return 0;
}
```

Function - DFS

```
long long int dfs(int i, int j, long long int ans)
{
    if(i==N) return ans;
    for(int itr = j; itr<=N; itr++)
    {
        if(P[itr] > P[i])
        {
            minans = min(minans, dfs(itr,itr+1,ans + (H[itr] - H[i])*(H[itr] - H[i]) + A[itr]));
            //printf("%d %lld\n",i,minans);
        }
    }
}
```

Variable minans is initialized as `111111111111`

Comment: undefined behaviour. your not returning a value from `dfs`

Comment: You need to enable more compiler warnings. Also, post a [mcve].

Comment: In the first line of dfs I'm returning a value.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: How can I do that?

Comment: The return value is being discarded anyway..

Comment: @user3811219 Depends on the compiler. With gcc and clang, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` is a good start.

Comment: Ohwait - no it's not, it's recursive.  My bad:(

Comment: I don't want the return value from that function. If the if statement is false than it's only when i<N.. So, I want the recursion to go until and N. 

Why does using a printf gives me the correct answer? :/ :(

Comment: What you want isn't going to happen. You're going to exit the `for` loop sooner or later and when you do you don't return anything. You also don't declare or initialize `minans`. Garbage is guaranteed to be the end result.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thanks :D I see now. :)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
return minans;
```

in your function and then in main use:

```
printf("**%lld\n",minans);
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem of `minans` never being declared or initialized.

Comment: @vishal: Please read the full post before. I've mentioned that minans is initialized as 111111111111.

Comment: @user3811219 Where is it declared ?

Comment: @user3811219 No, `minans` is not declared or initialized. You can't tell us code does one thing and then post code showing another. Post your real code or your question will get closed.

Comment: And that explains the abnormal behaviour, When I was using the printf than it was returning the value which printf returns.. so everything was getting covered with that and as soon I removed it.. printf was not returning any thing.. :( 
Thanks guys ! :)

Answer (score 0):

What if that `if` statment is `false`? Then your funtion `return`'s nothing . Thus undefined behaviour in that case.

You can `return` value of `minans` from function to `main` and then print it in `main` .

***Note-* I don't see `minans` declared in your program anywhere.**

Comment: `minans` isn't declared or initialized.